# UWP App package does not include *.csv files and *.config files

Tags: uwp

I have a simple UWP App from which I need to launch a Win32 App. I have followed all the instructions in the below link while creating the UWP App:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2016/12/19/desktop-bridge-the-migrate-phase-invoking-a-win32-process-from-a-uwp-app/

I have packaged all files related to the Win32 App (a Win32 exe, all dlls needed by the Win32 exe, *.xml files, *.config files and *.csv files needed by the Win32 App) by creating a separate Folder under my UWP Project.

I created the APPXBUNDLE file using Visual Studio (using Store -> Create App Packages -> Do you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Store (No) ).

The APPXBUNDLE file was successfully created. After installation (by double-clicking on APPXBUNDLE file), the UWP App was launched. But, *.config files and *.csv files needed by the Win32 App were not packaged as part of the UWP App even though I had added these files along with the Win32 exe and its dlls.

The Win32 exe reads from these *.csv files and *.config files at startup and is throwing a FileNotFoundException at startup.

Is there anything else that needs to be done to package *.csv files and *.config files as part of a UWP APP?

Comment: Did you set the file properties to "Content" and "Copy if Newer"?

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean. For *.csv and *.config files, Build Action was "None". After changing Build Action to "Content", these files are now included in the UWP App package and the Win32 App launch is successful.